# Populating database form from 2 tables (Access)

Tags: database, relationship, autofill

sorry to bother everyone, and this is a really easy question but i cant for the life of me word it correctly so that i can find a damn answer.

Sorry again but heres what im trying to do:

I have 2 tables, 
One contains a list of people, their contact information and the company they work for.
The other contains a list of companies, and the companies compact information

Then, I have a database form with the fields from both
What im trying to do is make a relationship where the database form sees that (for sake of an example) "Jane Doe" works for "Pixar" and that it fills the coresponding fields based on the contact information for pixar.

How would i make this work?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves me with allot of other questions to be able to form a short answer.

It sounds like you want to create a master / detail form.

I assume that the company id is in the people table and that you have added the relationship in the relationship editor.

Create a form for both tables then open the people form in design mode and drag and drop the company form onto the people form.

if you relationship is already defined in the relationship editor then access will automatically assign the correct parent child relationship fields of the forms.